# Getting the text inputted on a wkwebview from the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I have a section of the app where the user enters text into a wkwebview text field. I want to grab that entered text or record their key presses of the key board to display that text in another section of the app(they are typing in details to a third party). I have tried reading through the html, running java script to access the text field, I have even tried adding notification observers and tried overriding pressesBegan method. Is this possible, and how would I do it?

Comment: This sounds sketchy, like something you wouldn't be able to do by design. Even if your intentions are good, keylogging would probably get your app rejected. If your user is inputting to a third party website, you really shouldn't be able to see what they're inputting directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think observing the HTML is the right direction.

Instead, try to implement that with `WKScriptMessageHandler` would be much more standard and easier.